# Spring downloading files from multiple sources

Tags: java, spring, rest, design-patterns, architecture

I need to implement the functionality of downloading files from different sources (storages). The storage can be a separate server in the local network, a remote server, etc. Moreover, each storage has different data transfer protocols (like http, ftp) and different credentials. How can this be done? Is there a pattern for this? Or have you ever done something like this?

Comment: Check the [Strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern) pattern together with [Factory](https://www.baeldung.com/creational-design-patterns) pattern.
You can implemented the strategy interface which will be implemented by specific files downloading types. Then the particular Strategy can be created/invoked with the use of Factory Method pattern.

Comment: you should use a xml or yml file to define different connection info such as protocols and credentials.  it is helpful to your program configurable and extend. at some time, you need not change code and you just only change config file. you make a obj to analyze this file. then you pass different param to invoke different connection info. at this time, you may use above pattern as well.